# Java не получается прочитать xml

Tags: java, xml, dom

У меня есть файл xml. Он имеет такую структуру:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<tasks>
    <task file_id="3406" cont_name="D:\Data\cont\con1.dat" cont_offset="596672" file_size="16209"/>
    <task file_id="3608" cont_name="D:\Data\cont\con2.dat" cont_offset="39199605" file_size="101394"/>
    <task file_id="13435" cont_name="D:\Data\cont\con3.dat" cont_offset="28936" file_size="14900"/>
</tasks>
```

Моя задача, прочитать этот файл и достать значения атрибутов:

```
file_id
cont_name
cont_offset
file_size
```

Для чтения использую такой код:

```
File task_xml = new File("D:"+File.separator+
                                 "Data"+File.separator+
                                 "task"+File.separator+
                                 "task2.xml");

        if(task_xml.exists()){
        
            System.out.println("File exist");
        }
        
        DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();

        // Создается дерево DOM документа из файла
        Document document = documentBuilder.parse(task_xml);

        // Получаем корневой элемент
        Node root = document.getDocumentElement();
        System.out.println(root.getNodeName());
        System.out.println(root.getNodeValue());
        
        //Сохраняем все подэлементы корневого - т.е. task
        NodeList tasks = root.getChildNodes();
        //task равен null
         
        //Проходим по всем подэлементам root
        for (int i = 0; i < tasks.getLength(); i++) {
            
            Node task = tasks.item(i); 
            System.out.println(task.getNodeName()); //Текущая строчка <task....>

            //Сохранить все атрибуты этой строчки
            NamedNodeMap taskMap = task.getAttributes();
            
            //Пройтись по всем этим атрибутам
            for (int k = 0; k < taskMap.getLength(); k++) { 
            
                Node curAtribute = taskMap.item(i);
                System.out.println(curAtribute.getNodeName());
                System.out.println(curAtribute.getNodeValue());
                
            }
            
            //Перейти а след.строчку <task ...>

        } //Конец прохода по всем строчкам
```

Я могу прочитать главный элемент - root равный tasks, при этом если я хочу получить его Child, то на строчек:

```
        //Сохраняем все подэлементы корневого - т.е. task
        NodeList tasks = root.getChildNodes();
```

tasks равен null, как бы дочерних элементов нет. Но строчки же есть:

```
    <task file_id="3406" cont_name="D:\Data\cont\con1.dat" cont_offset="596672" file_size="16209"/>
    <task file_id="3608" cont_name="D:\Data\cont\con2.dat" cont_offset="39199605" file_size="101394"/>
    <task file_id="13435" cont_name="D:\Data\cont\con3.dat" cont_offset="28936" file_size="14900"/>
```

---

Подскажите как мне обратиться к этим вложенным строчка, и достать значения их атрибутов? Поискал методы как в ним обратиться и не нашел подходящего варианта. Или может и вовсе нужен другой способ сначала, подскажите пожалуйста как быть, заранее спасибо большое.

Comment: Проще всего такие вопросы решаются отладчиком. Посмотрите в отладчике содержимое переменной `root` - и все сразу станет ясно.

Comment: root равен tasks. Такой подход дал только те результаты, что я описал, есть еще идеи?

Comment: Если дочерних элементов нет, то должен возвращаться пустой список, но не null. Разве не так? Точно tasks == null?

Comment: Ну ты хардкорщик. Sax и dom давно устарели, го jaxb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для того, чтобы решить подобную задачу можно использовать библиотеку JDOM.

Для начала добавим зависимости в наш файл pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jdom</groupId>
    <artifactId>jdom</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Затем будем использовать следующий код:

```
        SAXBuilder parser = new SAXBuilder();
        org.jdom2.Document xmlDoc = parser.build(task_xml);
        
        //Получить вссе подэлементы <task>
        List children = xmlDoc.getRootElement().getChildren();
        
        Iterator i = children.iterator(); 
        
        while(i.hasNext()){ //Проход по всем подэлементам <task>
        
            Element nowTask = (Element) i.next();  //Текущий child элемента <task>
            
            //Параметры строчки
            String file_id = nowTask.getAttributeValue    ("file_id");       
            String cont_name = nowTask.getAttributeValue  ("cont_name");       
            String cont_offset = nowTask.getAttributeValue("cont_offset");       
            String file_size = nowTask.getAttributeValue  ("file_size");       
            
            System.out.println("task: "+file_id+" "
                                       +cont_name+" "
                                       +cont_offset+" "
                                       +file_size+" ");
            
        } //Переход на другую строчку
```

---

Тем самым получить обратиться к элементы  и достать его 3 вложенные строчки и дальше взаимодействовать с ними так как нужно. В моем примере, я обращаюсь к атрибутам этой строки.

Answer (score 1):

Смотрите комментарии в примере исходного кода:)

```
    //Сохраняем все ноды корневого - т.е. task и прочее неизвестное
    NodeList tasks = root.getChildNodes();
    //tasks не равен null
     
    //Проходим по всем нодам root
    for (int i = 0; i < tasks.getLength(); i++) {
        
        Node task = tasks.item(i);         

        // Дочерние ноды - это не только лишь подэлементы, 
        // но и прочий мусор, невидимый невооруженным глазом
        // Пропустим его
        if (task.getNodeType() != Element.ELEMENT_NODE) {
            continue;
        }
        
        System.out.println(task.getNodeName()); //Текущая строчка <task....>

        //Сохранить все атрибуты этой строчки
        NamedNodeMap taskMap = task.getAttributes();
        
        //Пройтись по всем этим атрибутам
        for (int k = 0; k < taskMap.getLength(); k++) { 
        
            Node curAtribute = taskMap.item(k); // <- здесь k должно быть
            System.out.println(curAtribute.getNodeName());
            System.out.println(curAtribute.getNodeValue());
            
        }
        
        //Перейти а след.строчку <task ...>

    } //Конец прохода по всем строчкам
```